# Reactions with a positive Delta H and a negative Delta S are said to be nonspontaneous at ALL temperatures. But what if the temperature IS low enough?

Tags: enthalpy, free-energy

What I mean is, that if you use G = H-TS and make the temperature low enough, couldn't you make any reaction spontaneous? For example, you have a Delta H of 85 kJ and a Delta S of -66 J/K. I've been told that this reaction is nonspontaneous at ALL temperatures, but if I make the temperature low enough, like around -1290 K, Delta G is now a negative value. Doesn't that mean that the reaction is now spontaneous at this temperature?

Comment: (-1) There is nothing below 0 K! This is absolute zero!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is simply terrible!

Comment: First off, you can't go below $0$ K. That's absolute zero like @EdV said
Secondly, since $0$ K is absolute zero, you can't have the value of the temperature in negatives.

Comment: I am against closing it because the question below provides a crucial information to OP and to everyone making this big mistake in future.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is not wrong but you are missing a critical piece of information that invalidates your conclusion. Namely, [temperature (on the absolute temperature scale) cannot go below zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_temperature).

Consider that temperature is effectively a measure of motion on the molecular scale, so you can imagine that there is a point at which all molecular motion stops.
This happens at 0 K, when all atoms are perfectly still (no rotation, no vibration, and so on) and it is not physically possible to lower the temperature any further.

If you put that limitation into the Gibbs free energy formula, you will see that there is no discrepancy.